# Standards and Precautions to be taken while starting a universal application in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-universal-app

Hi i need to create a universal application from scratch.are they any standards or precautions to be taken into consideration while starting a application.Can any one please steer me to some nice blogs or tutorials so that i can begin with it.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A lot of the tutorials that are out there are really for porting applications from iPhone to Universal style apps.

I'd start here:

["iOS App Programming Guide - Universal Apps"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW24)

This is useful as a style guide:

["iOS Human Interface Guidelines"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/UIElementGuidelines/UIElementGuidelines.html)

As well as these specific iOS controls that are useful:

[UISplitViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

[UIPopoverController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

The UIPopoverController in particular is what you'll need to wrap things in like the image picker.

If there's anything else ask in comments and I can update.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience there are 3 things you must be cautioned of when writing universal applications:

1: Size.  Your app can easily become bloated if you localize all of those xibs, or make separate classes for each device, or your method files could easily become cumbersome and hard to work with.  Also, the increased size of your bundle just might push you over the 20 mb limit for apps downloaded over 3G, thus alienating a small portion of potential buyers.

2: Testing.  Your app now requires you to test on not just older iPhones, but now older iPads.  Assuming you need backwards compatibility, that's a lot of builds to distribute!  If you just want to keep support for 4.x and later, there is always the simulator, but even then, the simulator is wacky when compared to an actual device.  Apple had to alter several drivers and strip out some features to get that simulator running, and even then, it's basically a Mac app (so it has full access to the more powerful CPU, GPU, etc.).

3: User Interface.  When the iPhone was first introduced and the app store was launched with iPhone OS 2.0, the iPhone's tiny screen made for some design challenges and big transitions for Mac developers who were used to 27'' iMacs.  Then the iPad came along and changed all that again!  Users on the iPhone and iPod front tend to want a more scaled back and ergonomic user interface without sacrificing features, whereas the iPad crowd tend to want features jammed into the thing, but features that are easily reachable on as few screens or wizards as possible.

That said, These are the perils of writing universal binaries, and in no way should this deter you.  Universal binaries tend to make most people happy and though they basically take twice the work, they are often worth it in the end.

EDIT:  I just realized that there aren't many good tutorials for writing universal applications online... Maybe Mr. Wenderlich will make one soon...